# use of multithreading for downloading in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-threads

I'm trying to concurrently download HTML-code of websites whose urls are stored in the database (about 3 millions of entries). 
It's obvious that I should use multithreading technology but I get into trouble how to do it in java. 

 Here's how I used to do it without multithreading:

```
final Connection c = dbConnect(); // register jdbc-driver and establish connection
checkRequiredDbAndTables();  // here we check the existence of the Db and necessary tables

try {
    // now get list of urls from the db
    String sql = "select id, website_url, category_id from list_of_websites";
    PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
    // column numeration in ResultSet is from 1 !
        final long id = rs.getInt(1);   // get website id
        final String url = rs.getString(2);   // get website url

        System.out.println("Category: " + rs.getString(3) + " " + id + " " + url);

        if ( isValidURL(url) && connectionOK(url) ) {
        // checked url syntax and connection 
            String htmlInPage = downloadHTML(url);
            if (!htmlInPage.equals("")) {
            // add result to db
                insertDataToDb( c, id, htmlInPage);
             }
        }
    }
    rs.close();
 } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
 }
    closeConnection(c);  // database connection closed
```

The function `donloadHTML` uses `JSoup` library to do the main work.

Feels like my task is a kind of "producer consumer problem". I suppose that it can be represented in a such way: there's a buffer, containing N links; some processes getting the links from it and downloading HTML; and a process, which aim is to load new urls from the db into the buffer as it gets empty. 
But I completely don't know how to do it. I've heard of `Threads` and `ExecutorService` providing `ThreadPools` but its really confusing for me.

Comment: Why is it obvious you should use multithreading for something that is IO-bound?

Comment: 1. You give code totally irrelevant to question. 2. Code uses methods we can't have opinions

Comment: You've "heard" of Threads and they confuse you? Have you tried *reading* about them to learn more? Like for example here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html

Comment: totally sure, cannot  create 3 million threads. In what environment is running this code ? Time is critical, or have all night to such "crawling" ?

Comment: @Jeff to be able to download 200 pages from fastwebsite.com while another thread is blocked waiting for slowwebsite.com to respond.

Comment: @JacekCz , 1) I gave code that I have now and want to change it in multithreading manner but don't know how 2) suppose this metods work properly. `protected Connection dbConnect() {
            String url = host + db;
            Class.forName(driver);  // Register JDBC driver
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password); // Open a connection
            return c;
        }` Of course, we should deal with exceptions

Comment: @JacekCz `public static String downloadHTML(String byLink) {
        String htmlInPage = "";
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(byLink).get();
            htmlInPage = doc.html();
        } catch (org.jsoup.UnsupportedMimeTypeException e) {
            //
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return htmlInPage;
    }`  `public static boolean isValidURL(String link) {
        UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator();
        return urlValidator.isValid(link);
    }
`

Comment: @JacekCz `public static boolean connectionOK(String toURL) {
        boolean connectionStatus = false;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(toURL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                connectionStatus = true;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return connectionStatus;
    }`

Comment: OK. stop please ;) Consider thread pool or/and queue in answers below

Comment: @JacekCz okay, thanx for your opinion)

Comment: @Andreas , I've even found this guide, but my problem still seems to be diffucult enough for me.

Comment: For future reference, don't post a bunch of unformatted code in comments like this...it's better to just update your question with new code.

Comment: @EvanLaHurd , thank you for your remark, I'll remember about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use a [Thread pool that has fixed amount of thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-). Your program will first [create a thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-). Then it will read URLs from database. When a URL is read, the program will [start a new task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.lang.Runnable-) to download its content.

You program may maintain a [queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html). When a task finish downloading HTMLs, it can push the URL and the result together into a queue. When the main thread finish reading URLs and starting tasks, it can wait for the queue. [Once the queue have any responses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html#isEmpty%28%29), [take the response out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html#poll%28%29) and write it to database. The main thread can count how many responses are received, when it counts to the number of URLs, then all task was finish.

Your program can write a class for storing the response with the URL, for example:

```
class response {
    public String URL;
    public String result;
    public response(String u, String r) { this.URL = u; this.result = r; }
}
```

If you still have any problem implementing or understanding ( I may not explain this clear enough, it is 00:40 now and I will probably go to sleep soon. ), please leave comments. If you want code, please also leave comments.

Comment: Thank you for the idea! I have now some working variant... http://pastebin.com/aC7kURMA Is it good? In fact, it required minimal changes in my original code, only to wrap it with Runnable. The solution with queue seems nice, but I already have 1 data structure: ResultSet - and afraid to create another, especially it there'll be a lot of data

Comment: @Tofrar You may not necessary only have 8 thread. It depends on your network speed. If the website don't restrict maximum parallel connection amount, you can have maybe 20 threads.

Comment: I increased ammount up to 20 threads, everything works fine. And very fast) I'll try to experiment and find the optimal number) Thank you!)

Answer (score 0):

Main thread:

- Start X "downloading" threads
- Run query shown in question. `for` each record:

  - Add data from query to an `ArrayBlockingQueue`
- Add end-of-data marker to queue
- Wait for threads to stop (optional)
- Return from `main`

Download thread:

- Get data from queue. `while` not end-of-data marker:

  - Download HTML
  - Insert HTML to database
- Put end-of-data marker back into queue for other threads to find
- Exit thread